# Windows 7 home premium keeps stopping working

Tags: windows-7

I have recently started using Windows7 home premium on an HP Pavilion DV6.

I constantly get messages saying MSWord has stopped working, or similar for using Powerpoint, trying to access documents, write emails etc. Some time later, ranging from seconds to minutes, I get the message **< word has restarted >**
This can happen several times during the process of writing a short document or email.

From the same location, I have been running Windows Vista Home Premium on
an Advent laptop without ever experiencing this problem.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that isn´t to be an OS problem. Probably you have the Microsoft Office corrupted, I suggest that you repair your Office, by uninstalling it, and eliminate the registry key.

Here is a link how to do it:

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/fix-microsoft-word-has-stopped-working/

Hope this can help you!